# Using CartThrob Subscriptions with Stripe checkout - Content Restrictions

Tags: cartthrob, subscriptions, stripe

Will I be able to use CartThrob Subscriptions with Stripe checkout in Europe?

And in general:

Do CT-subscriptions have a method of preventing access to content created by members, whose subscription expires? More specifically, I need to hide member profiles (zoo_visitor entries) once their plan is no longer paid for.

Thank you!

PS: I have already purchased Membrr and - while the addon is okay - their support is actually non-existant, so please don't suggest this! :)

Answer (score 3):

(I'm with Vector, the people who are now behind CartThrob. I know this is an old question but it still pops up on Google sometimes for some of our customers, so I'm answering it).

CartThrob Subscriptions fully supports Stripe in Europe (and any geography Stripe supports).

And, Subscriptions allows you to gate access to content or pages based on a user's membership status; for example, only allowing access to content while a Subscription is active.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest staying away from CartThrob in general, and Subscriptions in particular.  I had to fix a half dozen bugs in their Subscriptions code myself before my client's site was half functional, and there are still issues with the product.

Basic things like subscriptions rebilling, ending on expiration dates, etc. were all broken.

MightyRobot has actually pulled Subscriptions (and everything else except for CartThrob and CartThrob Manager) from sale, due to bugs and their inability to support the products.

Sadly, that leaves a vacuum in the subscription market for EE... but perhaps a custom solution along with something like Charge isn't a bad idea.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge

Comment: Wow, too bad! I purchased CartThrob about a year ago and always wondered, why I didn't get any answers to my recent support inquiries. :(

I guess they are focusing completely on their commercial support-options. What a pity!